# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, android-jetpack, android-camerax

Trying to use **CameraX** in Android.I am using [code link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0) .But i am facing Error
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method
    getLifecycle()Landroidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle; in class
    Landroidx/core/app/ComponentActivity; or its super classes

[image: Error image]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: Just shooting on the dark here (since no code is shown) but does the IDE warns you about not finding that specific method? If so, probably you are trying to access a protected method or something similar to that

Comment: @sanoJ  i am using codelabs code and i have mentioned link where you can find code.

Comment: @notihs i am using codelabs code and i have mentioned link where you can find code.

Comment: @Suman, i checked that code. The problem is in  the you have written in Android Studio. We are asking to post that code

Comment: @sanoJ please check this link : https://github.com/SumanPahari/CameraX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the appcompact dependency. If you check the source code of the version you are using `1.0.2`, there is no super method in the `ComponentActivity` class and the `FragmentActivity` is trying to call that method.

To **fix** this you need to **upgrade** the version to `1.1.0-rc01`. In this version `FragmentActivity` use a `LifecycleRegistry` to get the LifeCycle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Please update Android AppCompat Library V7
See latest version 1.1.0-rc01 but you are using 1.0.2
Please replace this line in build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

You will find updated dependencies from the below link.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat?repo=google

Answer (score 0):

> Add in build.gradle of app module

```
android { 

   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
```